# Ruby: get a list of extended modules?

Tags: ruby

When you include modules in a class or other module you can call

```
@mymod.included_modules
```

to get a list of modules included.

Is there an equivalent for listing the modules a module was extended by?

```
module Feature1
end

module Feature2
  extend Feature1
end

Feature2.extended_modules #=> [Feature1]
```

Comment: the ancestors function might be of some help

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
Feature2.singleton_class.included_modules # => [Feature1, ...]
```

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 19):

They're there, you just have to look in the right place:

```
(class << Feature2; self end).included_modules   # [Feature1, Kernel]
```

We can generalize like this:

```
class Module
  # Return any modules we +extend+
  def extended_modules
    (class << self; self end).included_modules
  end
end

# Now get those extended modules peculiar to Feature2
Feature2.extended_modules - Module.extended_modules # [Feature1]
```

Comment: Ah, yes.  I remember this now.  There's some German name associated with what this is.

Comment: I think the community has settled on *singleton class*. There's even an `Object#singleton_class` method in Ruby 1.9 which returns an object's singleton class. The reason why this works is of course that `extend` is literally just `singleton_class.include`.

Comment: I just tried your answer in irb and its awesome :)

but its singleton_class.included_modules

Answer (score 1):

All Ruby modules can be listed from **CLI (Command Line)**, itself as follows:

```
ruby -e 'puts Gem::Specification.all().map{|g| [g.name, g.version.to_s] }'
```

OR

```
ruby -rubygems -e 'puts Gem::Specification.all().map{|g| [g.name, g.version.to_s] }'
```

Hope this helps to some extent!!!